# UrlFetchApp.fetch throws error when URL passed as parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

If I have the following code:

```
function apiGET(someUrl){
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(someUrl);
  return result
}

result = apiGET("https://www.google.com")
Logger.log(result)
```

I get the following error: `DNS error: http://undefined (line 2, file "")`

But the log shows that the HTML is being returned as expected.

If I pass the fetch() method the string directly, I don't get an error and the same HTML is returned.

```
function apiGET(someUrl){
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com");
  return result
}

result = apiGET("https://www.google.com")
Logger.log(result)
```

What is the difference between passing a string as an argument, and passing a string directly?

---

The HTML from the 1st function is:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-ZA"><head><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'OaEwVo2vF4y0-QGZoYLADw',kEXPI:'3700314,4026240,4029815,4031109,4032678,4033307,4033344,4036527,4037333,4037569,4038012,4041440,4041836,4041897,4042492,4043255,4043448,4043449,4043492,4043804,4044246,4044606,4045841,4046304,4046348,4046400,4046976,4048007,4048011,4048142,4048512,4048513,4048570,4048770,4048854,4048909,4048971,4049597,4049605,4049896,4050137,4050322,4050495,4050735,4050780,4050802,4050906,4050911,4050925,4050926,4050991,4051107,4051195,4051283,4051314,8300096,8300227,8300272,8502095,8502221,8502312,8502315,8502342,8502444,8502483,8502528,8502535,8502537,10200083,10201365,10201409',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_10'};google.kHL='en-ZA';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(d){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,d,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var c=google.lc,f=google.li;c[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete c[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,d,e,g){var c="",f=google.ls||"";if(!d&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){var h=google.getEI(e),c="&ei="+h;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?c+="&lei="+e:h!=google.kEI&&(c+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=d||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+c+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.load=function(a,b,d){google.x({id:a+k++},function(){google.load(a,b,d)})};var k=0;})();var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0<a.indexOf("&q=")||0<=a.indexOf("#q="))&&(a=a.substring(1),-1==a.indexOf("#"))){for(var d=0;d<a.length;){var b=d;"&"==a.charAt(b)&&++b;var c=a.indexOf("&",b);-1==c&&(c=a.length);b=a.substring(b,c);if(0==b.indexOf("fp="))a=a.substring(0,d)+a.substring(c,a.length),c=d;else if("cad=h"==b)return 0;d=c}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}return 0}
function _gjh(){!_gjuc()&&window.google&&google.x&&google.x({id:"GJH"},function(){google.nav&&google.nav.gjh&&google.nav.gjh()})};window._gjh&&_gjh();</script><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;z-index:998;right:0}.gbto #gbs{background:#fff}#gbx3,#gbx4{background-color:#2d2d2d;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -138px;background-repeat:repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;height:29px;_height:30px;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:990}#gbx3{left:0}#gbx4{right:0}#gbb{position:relative}#gbbw{left:0;position:absolute;top:30px;width:100%}.gbtcb{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}#gbz .gbtcb{right:0}#gbg .gbtcb{left:0}.gbxx{display:none !important}.gbxo{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important}.gbm{position:absolute;z-index:999;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;text-align:left;border:1px solid #bebebe;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbrtl .gbm{-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbto .gbm,.gbto #gbs{top:29px;visibility:visible}#gbz .gbm{left:0}#gbg .gbm{right:0}.gbxms{background-color:#ccc;display:block;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:-1px;left:-2px;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;opacity:.4;-moz-border-radius:3px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);*opacity:1;*top:-2px;*left:-5px;*right:5px;*bottom:4px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";opacity:1\0/;top:-4px\0/;left:-6px\0/;right:5px\0/;bottom:4px\0/}.gbma{position:relative;top:-1px;border-style:solid dashed dashed;border-color:transparent;border-top-color:#c0c0c0;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;font-size:0;height:0;line-height:0;width:0;border-width:3px 3px 0;padding-top:1px;left:4px}#gbztms1,#gbi4m1,#gbi4s,#gbi4t{zoom:1}.gbtc,.gbmc,.gbmcc{display:block;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.gbmc{background:#fff;padding:10px 0;position:relative;z-index:2;zoom:1}.gbt{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;line-height:27px;padding:0;vertical-align:top}.gbt{*display:inline}.gbto{box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbzt,.gbgt{cursor:pointer;display:block;text-decoration:none !important}span#gbg6,span#gbg4{cursor:default}.gbts{border-left:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid transparent;display:block;*display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;position:relative;z-index:1000}.gbts{*display:inline}.gbzt .gbts{display:inline;zoom:1}.gbto .gbts{background:#fff;border-color:#bebebe;color:#36c;padding-bottom:1px;padding-top:2px}.gbz0l .gbts{color:#fff;font-weight:bold}.gbtsa{padding-right:9px}#gbz .gbzt,#gbz .gbgt,#gbg .gbgt{color:#ccc!important}.gbtb2{display:block;border-top:2px solid transparent}.gbto .gbzt .gbtb2,.gbto .gbgt .gbtb2{border-top-width:0}.gbtb .gbts{background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:-27px -22px;border:0;font-size:0;padding:29px 0 0;*padding:27px 0 0;width:1px}.gbzt:hover,.gbzt:focus,.gbgt-hvr,.gbgt:focus{background-color:#4c4c4c;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -102px;background-repeat:repeat-x;outline:none;text-decoration:none !important}.gbpdjs .gbto .gbm{min-width:99%}.gbz0l .gbtb2{border-top-color:#dd4b39!important}#gbi4s,#gbi4s1{font-weight:bold}#gbg6.gbgt-hvr,#gbg6.gbgt:focus{background-color:transparent;background-image:none}.gbg4a{font-size:0;line-height:0}.gbg4a .gbts{padding:27px 5px 0;*padding:25px 5px 0}.gbto .gbg4a .gbts{padding:29px 5px 1px;*padding:27px 5px 1px}#gbi4i,#gbi4id{left:5px;border:0;height:24px;position:absolute;top:1px;width:24px}.gbto #gbi4i,.gbto #gbi4id{top:3px}.gbi4p{display:block;width:24px}#gbi4id{background-position:-44px -101px}#gbmpid{background-position:0 0}#gbmpi,#gbmpid{border:none;display:inline-block;height:48px;width:48px}#gbmpiw{display:inline-block;line-height:9px;padding-left:20px;margin-top:10px;position:relative}#gbmpi,#gbmpid,#gbmpiw{*display:inline}#gbg5{font-size:0}#gbgs5{padding:5px !important}.gbto #gbgs5{padding:7px 5px 6px !important}#gbi5{background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:0 0;display:block;font-size:0;height:17px;width:16px}.gbto #gbi5{background-position:-6px -22px}.gbn .gbmt,.gbn .gbmt:visited,.gbnd .gbmt,.gbnd .gbmt:visited{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gbmt,.gbf .gbmt:visited{color:#900 !important}.gbmt,.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbmt:visited,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{color:#36c !important;text-decoration:none !important}.gbmt,.gbmt:visited{display:block}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{display:inline-block;margin:0 10px}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{*display:inline}.gbml1,.gbml1:visited{padding:0 10px}.gbml1-hvr,.gbml1:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}#gbpm .gbml1{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap}.gbmlb,.gbmlb:visited{line-height:27px}.gbmlb-hvr,.gbmlb:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}.gbmlbw{color:#ccc;margin:0 10px}.gbmt{padding:0 20px}.gbmt:hover,.gbmt:focus{background:#eee;
```

The HTML from the 2nd function is:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-ZA"><head><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'kaEwVszjKMXv-QG8jqG4Bw',kEXPI:'3700279,4029572,4029815,4031109,4032678,4033307,4033344,4036527,4037333,4037569,4038012,4040138,4041440,4041837,4042158,4042490,4043255,4043457,4043492,4044246,4044606,4045841,4046304,4046400,4046422,4046976,4048007,4048011,4048142,4048452,4048512,4048513,4048570,4048628,4048854,4048901,4048909,4048972,4049198,4049597,4049896,4050323,4050496,4050500,4050735,4050742,4050779,4050802,4050905,4051038,4051282,8300096,8300227,8300261,8300272,8502095,8502221,8502312,8502314,8502341,8502443,8502483,8502529,8502535,8502537,10200083,10201366,10201409,10201434,10201476,10201487',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_10'};google.kHL='en-ZA';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(d){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,d,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var c=google.lc,f=google.li;c[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete c[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,d,e,g){var c="",f=google.ls||"";if(!d&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){var h=google.getEI(e),c="&ei="+h;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?c+="&lei="+e:h!=google.kEI&&(c+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=d||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+c+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.load=function(a,b,d){google.x({id:a+k++},function(){google.load(a,b,d)})};var k=0;})();var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0<a.indexOf("&q=")||0<=a.indexOf("#q="))&&(a=a.substring(1),-1==a.indexOf("#"))){for(var d=0;d<a.length;){var b=d;"&"==a.charAt(b)&&++b;var c=a.indexOf("&",b);-1==c&&(c=a.length);b=a.substring(b,c);if(0==b.indexOf("fp="))a=a.substring(0,d)+a.substring(c,a.length),c=d;else if("cad=h"==b)return 0;d=c}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}return 0}
function _gjh(){!_gjuc()&&window.google&&google.x&&google.x({id:"GJH"},function(){google.nav&&google.nav.gjh&&google.nav.gjh()})};window._gjh&&_gjh();</script><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;z-index:998;right:0}.gbto #gbs{background:#fff}#gbx3,#gbx4{background-color:#2d2d2d;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -138px;background-repeat:repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;height:29px;_height:30px;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:990}#gbx3{left:0}#gbx4{right:0}#gbb{position:relative}#gbbw{left:0;position:absolute;top:30px;width:100%}.gbtcb{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}#gbz .gbtcb{right:0}#gbg .gbtcb{left:0}.gbxx{display:none !important}.gbxo{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important}.gbm{position:absolute;z-index:999;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;text-align:left;border:1px solid #bebebe;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbrtl .gbm{-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbto .gbm,.gbto #gbs{top:29px;visibility:visible}#gbz .gbm{left:0}#gbg .gbm{right:0}.gbxms{background-color:#ccc;display:block;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:-1px;left:-2px;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;opacity:.4;-moz-border-radius:3px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);*opacity:1;*top:-2px;*left:-5px;*right:5px;*bottom:4px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";opacity:1\0/;top:-4px\0/;left:-6px\0/;right:5px\0/;bottom:4px\0/}.gbma{position:relative;top:-1px;border-style:solid dashed dashed;border-color:transparent;border-top-color:#c0c0c0;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;font-size:0;height:0;line-height:0;width:0;border-width:3px 3px 0;padding-top:1px;left:4px}#gbztms1,#gbi4m1,#gbi4s,#gbi4t{zoom:1}.gbtc,.gbmc,.gbmcc{display:block;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.gbmc{background:#fff;padding:10px 0;position:relative;z-index:2;zoom:1}.gbt{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;line-height:27px;padding:0;vertical-align:top}.gbt{*display:inline}.gbto{box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbzt,.gbgt{cursor:pointer;display:block;text-decoration:none !important}span#gbg6,span#gbg4{cursor:default}.gbts{border-left:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid transparent;display:block;*display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;position:relative;z-index:1000}.gbts{*display:inline}.gbzt .gbts{display:inline;zoom:1}.gbto .gbts{background:#fff;border-color:#bebebe;color:#36c;padding-bottom:1px;padding-top:2px}.gbz0l .gbts{color:#fff;font-weight:bold}.gbtsa{padding-right:9px}#gbz .gbzt,#gbz .gbgt,#gbg .gbgt{color:#ccc!important}.gbtb2{display:block;border-top:2px solid transparent}.gbto .gbzt .gbtb2,.gbto .gbgt .gbtb2{border-top-width:0}.gbtb .gbts{background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:-27px -22px;border:0;font-size:0;padding:29px 0 0;*padding:27px 0 0;width:1px}.gbzt:hover,.gbzt:focus,.gbgt-hvr,.gbgt:focus{background-color:#4c4c4c;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -102px;background-repeat:repeat-x;outline:none;text-decoration:none !important}.gbpdjs .gbto .gbm{min-width:99%}.gbz0l .gbtb2{border-top-color:#dd4b39!important}#gbi4s,#gbi4s1{font-weight:bold}#gbg6.gbgt-hvr,#gbg6.gbgt:focus{background-color:transparent;background-image:none}.gbg4a{font-size:0;line-height:0}.gbg4a .gbts{padding:27px 5px 0;*padding:25px 5px 0}.gbto .gbg4a .gbts{padding:29px 5px 1px;*padding:27px 5px 1px}#gbi4i,#gbi4id{left:5px;border:0;height:24px;position:absolute;top:1px;width:24px}.gbto #gbi4i,.gbto #gbi4id{top:3px}.gbi4p{display:block;width:24px}#gbi4id{background-position:-44px -101px}#gbmpid{background-position:0 0}#gbmpi,#gbmpid{border:none;display:inline-block;height:48px;width:48px}#gbmpiw{display:inline-block;line-height:9px;padding-left:20px;margin-top:10px;position:relative}#gbmpi,#gbmpid,#gbmpiw{*display:inline}#gbg5{font-size:0}#gbgs5{padding:5px !important}.gbto #gbgs5{padding:7px 5px 6px !important}#gbi5{background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:0 0;display:block;font-size:0;height:17px;width:16px}.gbto #gbi5{background-position:-6px -22px}.gbn .gbmt,.gbn .gbmt:visited,.gbnd .gbmt,.gbnd .gbmt:visited{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gbmt,.gbf .gbmt:visited{color:#900 !important}.gbmt,.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbmt:visited,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{color:#36c !important;text-decoration:none !important}.gbmt,.gbmt:visited{display:block}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{display:inline-block;margin:0 10px}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{*display:inline}.gbml1,.gbml1:visited{padding:0 10px}.gbml1-hvr,.gbml1:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}#gbpm .gbml1{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap}.gbmlb,.gbmlb:visited{line-height:27px}.gbmlb-hvr,.gbmlb:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}.gbmlbw{color:#ccc;margin:0 10px}.gbmt{padding:0 20px}.gbmt:hover,.gbmt:focus{background:#e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GAS calling functions globablly doesn't work so well, you can't do that, if you pass it in from another funciton it works just fine:

```
function apiGET(someUrl){
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(someUrl);
  return result
}

function runTest(){
  result = apiGET("https://www.google.com")
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize i was calling the function to invoke the script (which was getting an error back), and then the function was being invoked and printing out the HTML. I think it's interesting though that the error doesn't stop the script

Comment: That is despite the fact that the function is being called without a parameter before the function is called with a parameter (unless that's not actually what happens when you invoke a GAS script through a function)